# SQLAlchemy relationship not updated after flush

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have some models with a relationship defined between them like so:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    children = Relationship(Child, lazy='joined')

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    father_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), nullable=False)
```

If I add a child within the session (using `session.add(Child(...))`), I would expect its father's children relationship to update to include this child after flushing the session. However, I'm not seeing that.

```
parent = session.query(Parent).get(parent_id)
num_children = len(parent.children)
# num_children == 3, for example

session.add(Child(father_id=parent_id))
session.flush()

new_num_children = len(parent.children)
# num_children == 3, it should be 4!
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

I can add the new child to the `parent.children` list directly, and flush the session, but I'm due to other existing code, I want to add it using `session.add`.

I can also `commit` after adding the child, which does correctly update the `parent.children` relationship, but I don't want to commit the transaction at the point.

I've tried adding a `backref` to the `children` relationship, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: For me in similar situation helped add of both child and parent to the session

Answer (score 17):

I've just run into this problem myself. SQLAlchemy does some internal memoisation to prevent it emitting a new SQL query every time you access a relationship. The problem is that it doesn't seem to realise that updating the foreign key directly could have an effect on the relationship. While SQLAlchemy probably could be patched to deal with this for simple joins, it would be very difficult for complex joins and I presume this is why it behaves the way it does.

When you do `session.flush()`, you're sending the changes back to the database, but SQLAlchemy doesn't realise it needs to query the database to update the relationship.

If you call `session.expire_all()` after the flush, then you force SQLAlchemy to reload every model instance and relationship when they're next accessed - this solves the problem.

You can also use `session.expire(obj)` to do this more selectively or `session.refresh(obj)` to do it selectively and immediately re-query the database.

For more information about these methods and how they differ, I found a helpful blog post: https://www.michaelcho.me/article/sqlalchemy-commit-flush-expire-refresh-merge-whats-the-difference

Official docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html